# Properly centering an element with z-index

Tags: html, css, centering

Structure of page:

```
div#help
-- div
  -- ul
    -- li
    -- li
-- div
  -- ul
    -- li
    -- li
-- div.message_shower
  -- p  /*small `x` for close button*/
  -- div.content
```

Whenever any list item `<li>`is clicked, a `div.message_shower` opens having some text.

---

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9s08g1rg/2/)** (you may ignore the JS and HTML tab)

---

**Problem:** I want to center the `div.message_shower` in the screen, both horizontally and vertically. Even after using percentage units, it is not working. `margin: 0 auto;` does not work either. Note that `.message_shower` has a `z-index` of `2`.

Normal screen - centered properly:

[image: load image]

A screen only a bit small - not centered properly:

[image: load image]

Here's how it should be properly in small screen:

[image: load image]

---

Support required for Google Chrome only

**Note:** If I scroll down, it should not get scrolled and hidden. I want it (`.message_shower`) to stay in the visible screen area.

**UPDATE:** I will wait for a week, and if I do not get any answer that actually center the div (@mutil's answer widens the div), I will accept @mutil's answer.

Comment: works for google chrome  36.0.1985.143 m

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Please view this: http://s27.postimg.org/flkepec2r/proper.png - does the message shower look like that for you? Please send a screenshot in case it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding

```
width: calc(100% - 200px);
margin: 0 70px;
```

and removing `left: 30%;` from `.message_shower`?

It's not fixed sized anymore but it stays in center.

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9s08g1rg/4/)

---

If you want the div to be of exact width, you can set both left and right to zero and margin to auto.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9s08g1rg/6/)

Comment: Thank you! It stays in the center, but if I scroll down, it gets scrolled. I want it to stay in the visible screen area.

Comment: You can change `position: absolute` to `position: fixed` and maybe reduce the top then.